# Import SVM light file format in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, svmlight

I am trying to use NLTK for training a Naive Bayes classifier for multi-class text classification. But I do not have access to the original texts. I am provided with is a file in SVM Light format (one instance each line with feature:value pair). I simply have to import this file and train and test Naive Bayes classifier using this dataset. I was wondering if there is some way to import this file into NLTK and use it directly for training classifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/)'s own documentation this is achieved something like this:

**Excerpt from Documentation:**

> scikit-learn (http://scikit-learn.org) is a machine learning library
>   for Python. It supports many classification algorithms, including
>   SVMs, Naive Bayes, logistic regression (MaxEnt) and decision trees.
>
> This package implement a wrapper around scikit-learn classifiers. To
>   use this wrapper, construct a scikit-learn estimator object, then use
>   that to construct a SklearnClassifier. E.g., to wrap a linear SVM with
>   default settings:

**Example:**

```
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
>>> classif = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
```

See: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify.scikitlearn

Comment: do note that you're using `sklearn` to convert the corpus into svm format and use nltk's wrapper to `sklearn` to call the classifier.